# Posting a php variable to a new window

Tags: php

I have a page that is dynamically built by the database. For each thing that is built dynamically, I want to have a link that pops up a new window and that new window will populate a list from the database, based on which item on the first page was clicked. I have tried POST methods and posting the variable to the url (which I know is dangerous). The other thing that makes this unique is that the link that is clicked is really not a link to a page, but I do some Javascript to call a function that opens a new window and a new php page because it would be silly to open a whole new page for just a list. How do I do this? If you need more clarification I will do my best to make it clearer.

I am building a table and it will have links like this:

```
<td><a href="#" style="font-weight:normal; font-style:italic" onclick="function()">Do Stuff</a></td>
```

`function function(){
            window.open("page.php", "blank"," toolbar=no, width=400, height=350, top=50, left=50, scrollbars=yes");
        }`

The function() will open a new window with a new php page. The question is how to get the php variable over to the new window.

Comment: Please elaborate your issue with some sample coding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simple ver

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('youPopUpPage.php?value=$value');\">link</a>";
```

into youPopUpPage.php

```
$value=$_GET["value"]; # retrive value from calling page
```

open with js function

```
<td><a href="#" style="font-weight:normal; font-style:italic" onclick="openPage(<?php echo $value ;?>)">Do Stuff</a></td>


<script type="text/javascript">
function openPage(value){
window.open('youPopUpPage.php?value='+value);}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! I am new to Javascript, and I actually wondered if this method was possible. Thanks a million, you are a gentleman and a scholar.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your just passing ID's that don't mean anything to anyone then do something like this with your links:

```
echo "<a href='/myaddress?id=".$id."'>my link</a>";
```

On the new window you will then be able to get to the value with get:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

With this id you should be able to look in your database to find the actual content you want.

Comment: This won't work as my link does not directly go to an address, it first calls a js function.

Comment: So then pass the value into that function, and make the function add it to the request.