# PHP Pass Variable to new Window.Open Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, variables

I have read the following posts, but they are a little over the top for me. I think I'm trying to do something fairly simple, and would like some guidance.

[How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

[passing PHP variables across javascript windows.open to another PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956251/passing-php-variables-across-javascript-windows-open-to-another-php-page)

[Posting a php variable to a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227404/posting-a-php-variable-to-a-new-window)

Here is the case:

I have a php script which is very simple, it calls another script and passes 2 variables:

```
<?php
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
window.open("http://callpage.com/utils/cdr.php?callernum=123456789&calltime=2017-02-22 16:24:12");
</script>';
?>
```

Note: This is just a "hardcoded" example.

The next script, takes those numbers and builds file/url variable.

Lets say

```
$file = /var/www/html/file.wav
```

What I'm trying to do open a new window to the effect of :

```
http://newpage.com/$file
```

I have read and found that I think the best use is Javascript, but I can't seem to get my variable into the Javascript.

Here is what I would like to get working:

```
<?php 
$file = /var/www/html/file.wav
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
window.open("http://newpage.com/$file"); 
</script>'; 
?>
```

A few notes:

- I don't want to "redirect" the old page, I want it to stay open, and the remote page isn't on the same domain 
  (one is a.domain.com and the other is b.domain.com).
- I don't care about window sizes, etc, its a wav file that I'm expecting the browser to just play with a simple Browser default interface for Wav.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use string interpolation with double quotes for the echo statement and single quotes everywhere inside the javascript:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'> 
window.open('http://newpage.com/$file'); 
</script>";
```

The interpolated PHP variable $file should be correctly interpreted as a string and the value it holds should be displayed in the URI of your javascript.
Check out this easy to understand info about variable interpolation http://phppot.com/php/variable-interpolation-in-php/

Comment: I prefer this method, as the double quotes take care of all variables added, vs the other answer seems prone to mistakes, but both worked! so +1 for both.

Comment: I am at risk of not being able to ask any more questions, if you think this was well documented and although a duplicate, worth "re-asking", consider an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

if I understood correctly what you want, you have to concatenate the string with the variable in order to be replaceed

```
<?php
$file = '/var/www/html/file.wav';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
          window.open("http://newpage.com/'.$file.'");
      </script>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "final" code snippet:

```
$query->execute();

while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  $uid = $row['uniqueid'];

  foreach(glob($path. "*". $uid. "*") as $file) {
  $link = "http://newpage.com$file";

  echo "<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
  window.open('$link');
  </script>";

  }
 }
```